# how to place a columnFilter near Search box in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is there a way to place the columnFilter near Search box in jQuery DataTables? And how to add a label for this columnFilter dropdown?

The below code places the filter on the header:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
   "bJQueryUI": true
}).columnFilter({
   sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
   aoColumns: [null, { type: "select" }, null, null, null]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At first the author said that this datatable plug-in doesn't support putting the filter on other postion, but finally I find [this](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/external.html) , which can meet you requirement that can put the filter element on other position.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. Kindly refrain yourself from posting link only answers. While the link may answer the question, it is always good to add a brief of the answer.